# sessionStorage: 10 itens diferentes com o mesmo nome

Tags: javascript

Amigos, estou fazendo um sessionStorage para 10 itens. Eu estou contabilizando cada clique que faço em uma div e somo um númerol. até aí tudo bem, mas que que esse número volte ao zero quando clico em cada um dos próximos itens.
Segue o cógigo;

```
<div class="element-item idade1 etaria" data-category="etaria"  onClick="addIdade(1);">
<div class="element-item idade1 etaria" data-category="etaria"  onClick="addIdade(2);">
```

etc.

e o JS:

```
    function addIdade(idade) {
if (sessionStorage.clickcount) {
    sessionStorage.clickcount = Number(sessionStorage.clickcount) + 1;
} else {
    sessionStorage.clickcount = 1;
}
document.getElementById("idade"+idade).innerHTML =  + sessionStorage.clickcount;
sessionStorage.removeItem("conforto");
}
```

Porque isso? Pois quando clico no próximo item, obviamente já aparece o valor da variável "clickcount" guardada no sessionStorage. Por exe.: Se clico 4 vezes no idade1(vai de 0 a 4) e depois uma vez no idade9 já começa no 5 e eu quero que comece do 0 novamente.

Agradeço uma ajuda!

Comment: E se usar o sessionStorage.setItem('chave', 'valor');